# Identity Server 3 - Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I'm trying to use the IdentityServer3(Version: 2.0.0.0) in a signed c# application.

Currently, I've an Identity Server 3 in a c# mvc application(unsigned) that authenticates users to access a resource server.

Any help will be highly appreciated to solve this error. Please check the stack trace and steps for more details.

**Steps:**

1. Signed All the Application in the project using a private snk file.
2. Signed the IdentityServer3.dll & IdentityServer3.Localization.dll using a keypairXXXX.snk file(Tools used: ILDASM.exe & ILASM.exe)
3. Added [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProduct.IdentityServer3,PublicKey=00240...........)]
   in the AssemblyInfo.cs of the MyProduct project.

When i start the application, it throws the exception:

> "C:\users\PC140\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8ccd1c62\b8638244\assembly\dl3\ef0da3d7\6005806e_edcad301\IdentityServer3.dll]
>   Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their
>   InternalsVisibleTo declarations."

**Stack Trace:**

> [MethodAccessException: [C:\users\PC140\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8ccd1c62\b8638244\assembly\dl3\ef0da3d7\6005806e_edcad301\IdentityServer3.dll]
>   Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their
>   InternalsVisibleTo declarations.]
>   ResourceIdentityServer.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in
>   E:\Build_Project\Myproduct-Resource\Myproduct-Resource-Main\Resource
>   Identity Server\Startup.cs:81
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +150
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +101    Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +66
>   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder
>   builder) +123
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IAppBuilder
>   builder) +71
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1
>   startup) +462
>
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +40 
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
>   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target,
>   Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +106
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10043436
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254